# How can I create a bootable media image that provides automated recovery?

Tags: disk-image, imaging, clonezilla, acronis

I have clients/employees who use company workstations and want to create a dedicated restore partition on the drive such that when they boot into it, it boots into an automated recovery sequence, and restores a particular partition to a particular image using pre-set parameters(i.e. on startup: run_restore(sourcedisk, destinationdisk, "/image_location") ).

I have acronis backup, and I actually placed a their bootable media image on a local partition, but I really don't want any customers or end-users to use acronis as I feel it provides too many choices and too many butterflies may be stepped on :P. Clonezilla has this ability but It is no longer an option for me because it doesn't seem to be able to write to the raid volume (as opposed to the disk) properly.

According to Acronis, they don't provide this functionality, but their bootable media is based off of a Linux partition, and I can start a bash shell. Would I be able to just create a startup script file and place it in /etc and set it to run on startup to initiate an acronis recovery process?

Or, do any of you know of any free cloning/imaging software that has the ability to create a bootmedia with set parameters to run an automated system restore?

Thank you.

(btw, I would like this to be on a separate partition in case the OS(or partition) is so screwed that it wont even boot; they can still boot to the recovery partition)

Comment: can you not go down the pxe boot path. Would be much simpler and can be fully automated?

Comment: @Drifter104 No, unfortunately, the pxe boot route wouldn't be cost effective with Acronis; and the image file is about 17GB, so I'd like to avoid pulling it over a WAN( the remote clients and customers are far away ) regardless of the vendor.